# CSS - background atribute doesn't work on mobile browser

Tags: css, background

I have a problem with background of an element in my website. On PC browser, this element is looking that:

[image]

but on mobile phone, this element is looking that:

[image]

Why this icon "X" can't be display on mobile phones? Here is my CSS code:

```
.select2-search-choice-close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 13px;
  font-size: 1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('http://mysite.pl/templates/default/panel/img/select2.png');
  background-position: right top; 
  outline: none;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

EDIT:

The problem is with this layout: https://wrappixel.com/demos/free-admin-templates/maruti-admin/form-common.html

Comment: `right:3px` shouldn't be left ?

Comment: No, on PC it's ok. I changed for right: 3px but then it doesn't work fine on PC and mobile phone too.

Comment: I added live demo in my post, look please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On mobile there is another style overriding the background image as you can see in this screenshot :

[image]

As you can see it's on the line 475 of your file, so simply edit/remove it.